# Why am I getting a segmentation fault? (Testing Shellcode)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, shellcode

I wrote a simple ASM file and ran it in a C file I'd written. I got a segentation fault. However, when I execute the compiled ASM file, I get no error.

I am running 64 bit and using 32 bit shellcode. Is that the issue?

It can't be, because I'm getting a segmentation fault with this:

```
char shellcode[] = "\x90"; //simple NOP in ASM
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int (*ret)();
  ret = (int (*)()) shellcode;
  (int)(*ret)();
}
```

Can someone please run this and tell me whether or not they get a segmentation fault. I have used 3 or 4 other C files as well. None have worked.

**Update:**

```
((void(*)(void))code)();
```

Seems to be working in place of those three lines.

Comment: That is not how you use inline assembler... first, which compiler are you using? [Here](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rmiyagi-inline-asm.txt) is how you do it with "gcc".

Comment: I think we have a problem of endian　and stack frame.

Comment: On what platform (what operating system, what compiler)? It could be because your heap isn't executable.

Comment: `"/x90"` is supposed to be an address?

Comment: It's unlikely that an x86-64 OS will let you execute data in any case.

Comment: @Gilles What heap are you referring to? His "shellcode" is not on the heap.

Comment: @claptrap Sorry, right, static data. But the point still stands — it may be in a non-executable zone depending on the platform.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the responses. A friend informed me that my C is what "needs a lot of work". Using `((void(*)(void))shellcode)();` works. I'm getting confused on the pointers casting as function syntax.

Comment: I get the same issue, but this doesn't work for me either:(. I think I have to install a 32bits ubuntu.

Comment: I just try on my ubuntu 32 bits, not working either :(

Comment: I asked a very similar question a while ago, and received quite a good answer to it, given by @Drew McGowen: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25311861/1382251.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned above the shellcode is in non-executable memory. Try recompiling the program with the -fno-stack-protector and the -z execstack flags enabled.

That is:

> gcc **-fno-stack-protector** **-z execstack** -O OutputFileName yourShellCode.c

Comment: Alternatively, one can also run `execstack OutputFileName` on a binary already compiled without these supplementary parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. The shell code might be in non-executable memory.  In order to make it executable, you need to either ask the OS to make it executable (e.g. with [`mprotect(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) or [`VirtualProtect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), or allocate new executable memory and copy it there (e.g. with [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) or [`VirtualAlloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Your shell code doesn't return/exit.  After the CPU executes your NOP there (0x90), it's going to keep on executing code in the memory that comes after that NOP instruction.  Most likely, this will crash quickly, but it might do other random, unpredictable things.

To fix #2, you need to explicitly either execute a return instruction (`C3` on x86/x86-64) to return from your shell code, or you need to do something which never returns, like call the [`exit(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) function.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should change your variable :

```
   char shellcode[]
```

To:

```
   const char shellcode[]
```

Like in this question:
[segmentation-fault-error-when-exe-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076525/segmentation-fault-error-when-exe-c)

This one worked for me! :)

Comment: that did it!
OS: Arch Linux x86_64
Kernel Release: 4.9.8-1-ARCH
Uptime: 2:41
WM: i3
DE: None
Packages: 765
RAM: 2405 MB / 5963 MB
Processor Type: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 430  @ 2.27GHz
$EDITOR: None
Root: 16G / 69G (23%) (ext4)

Answer (score 2):

Try put the shellcode in the main function to make it a local variable:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char shellcode[] = "<your shellcode>";
  int (*ret)();
  ret = (int (*)()) shellcode;
  (int)(*ret)();
}
```

Then compile it with flags `-fno-stack-protector` and `-z execstack`:

```
gcc <filename>.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o <filename>
```

I found this idea on [stackexchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30098/shellcode-not-running-as-expected-showing-segmentation-fault-core-dump) and it worked for me.